# Columns to rows and rows to column conversion without pivot/unpivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

All I need is convert Column(A1/A2) into rows and rows(1 into Jan) into columns.
Input:

Here A1/A2 belongs to say A and they are calculated as A1/A2 for each month.

```
Month   A1  A2  B1  B2  C1  C2
1      120  60  40  80  120 120
2      50   50  40  20  60  30
3      50   25  40  10  90  30
```

I need below o/p without using pivot and unpivot

O/P:

```
X   Jan(1 is denoting Jan)     Feb      Mar
A   120/60(calculation:A1/A2)   40/80   120/120
B   50/50                      40/20    60/30
C   50/25                       40/10   90/30
```

I tried but my query is too long as I am using `case` and `Union All` three times each For A1 A2,B1 B2,C1 C2 etc.

Comment: Do you want the evaluation of the expression (e.g. 120/60) or that string value?

Answer (score 0):

Using `cross apply(values ...)` and conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    v.X
  , Jan = max(case when t.month=1 then v.Value end)
  , Feb = max(case when t.month=2 then v.Value end)
  , Mar = max(case when t.month=3 then v.Value end)
from t
  cross apply(values
    ('A',convert(varchar(3),A1)+'/'+convert(varchar(3),A2))
   ,('B',convert(varchar(3),B1)+'/'+convert(varchar(3),B2))
   ,('C',convert(varchar(3),C1)+'/'+convert(varchar(3),C2))
  ) v (X,Value)
group by v.X
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/XICI74484

returns:

```
+---+---------+-------+-------+
| X |   Jan   |  Feb  |  Mar  |
+---+---------+-------+-------+
| A | 120/60  | 50/50 | 50/25 |
| B | 40/80   | 40/20 | 40/10 |
| C | 120/120 | 60/30 | 90/30 |
+---+---------+-------+-------+
```

---

For the evaluation of the expressions:

```
select 
    v.X
  , Jan = max(case when t.month=1 then v.Value end)
  , Feb = max(case when t.month=2 then v.Value end)
  , Mar = max(case when t.month=3 then v.Value end)
from t
  cross apply(values
    ('A',(A1*1.0)/A2)
   ,('B',(B1*1.0)/B2)
   ,('C',(C1*1.0)/C2)
  ) v (X,Value)
group by v.X
```

returns:

```
+---+------+------+------+
| X | Jan  | Feb  | Mar  |
+---+------+------+------+
| A | 2.00 | 1.00 | 2.00 |
| B | 0.50 | 2.00 | 4.00 |
| C | 1.00 | 2.00 | 3.00 |
+---+------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use XML.  This snippet may be more than you want but it shows how

```
--------------------------------------------------
-----------------Begin  TRANSPOSE-----------------
--------------------------------------------------     

DECLARE @xml XML
   ,@RowCount BIGINT 

DECLARE @sSQl NVARCHAR(MAX)= 'SELECT (SELECT DISTINCT ColumnName FROM #TempTable WHERE CellId=Cell.CellId) as ColumnName,' 

---------------------------------------------------
--Set up #table Here or outside the code... but #TABLE WILL BE DROPPED AT FINISH
---------------------------------------------------

--#############################################################################
-- the temp table #Table will contain what you want to Transpose
--############################################################################# 

--SELECT * INTO #Table FROM Widgets W WHERE WidgetId IN (1096,803)


---------------------------------------------------
----------------  End #Table Setup  ---------------
---------------------------------------------------

SET @xml = (SELECT  *
                   ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1
                                                )) Rn
            FROM    #Table Row
           FOR
            XML AUTO
               ,ROOT('Root')
               ,ELEMENTS XSINIL
           );  

WITH  RC AS 

    (SELECT COUNT(Row.value('.', 'nvarchar(MAX)')) [RowCount]  

    FROM @xml.nodes('Root/Row') AS WTable(Row))  

 ,c AS(  

 SELECT b.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)') ColumnName,  
   b.value('.[not(@xsi:nil = "true")]','nvarchar(max)') Value,  
   b.value('../Rn[1]','nvarchar(max)') Rn,  

   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b.value('../Rn[1]','nvarchar(max)') ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) Cell  

 FROM 

  @xml.nodes('//Root/Row/*[local-name(.)!="Rn"]') a(b)  
  ),Cols AS (  

  SELECT  DISTINCT c.ColumnName, 
   c.Cell  
  FROM c  
  )  

  INSERT INTO #TempTable (CellId,RowID,Value,ColumnName)  
  SELECT Cell,Rn,Value,REPLACE(c.ColumnName,'_x0023_','#')  
  FROM c  


SELECT  @sSQL = @sSQl + '(SELECT T2.Value FROM #Temptable T2 WHERE T2.CellId=Cell.CellID AND T2.Rowid=' + CAST(T.RowId AS NVARCHAR) + ') AS __________________Value____________________'
        + CAST(T.RowID AS NVARCHAR) + ','
FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT
                RowId
         FROM   #TempTable
        ) T  

SET @sSQl = LEFT(@sSQL, LEN(@sSQL) - 1) + ' FROM (SELECT DISTINCT CellId FROM #TempTable) Cell order by columnname' 
EXECUTE sp_Executesql @sSQl  

 --here you will have your output  
 -- PRINT @sSQl
DROP TABLE #Table 
DROP TABLE #TempTable 


--------------------------------------------------
-----------------END  TRANSPOSE-------------------
--------------------------------------------------
```